# unexpected result from regular expression of url

Tags: regex, shell

I am trying to match one part in a url. This url has already been processed and consists of domain name only.

For example:

The url I have now is   business.time.com
Now I want to get rid of the top level domain(.com). The result I want is   business.time

I am using the following code:

```
gawk'{
match($1, /[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+[^(.com|.org|.edu|.gov|.mil)]/, where)
print where[0]
print where[1]
}' test
```

In test, there are four lines:

```
business.time.com
mybest.try.com
this.is.a.example.org
this.is.another.example.edu
```

I was expecting this :

```
business.time

mybest.try

this.is.a.example

this.is.another.example
```

However, the output is

```
business.t

mybest.try

this.is.a.examp

this.is.another.examp
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong and what should I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use the dot as field separator and do:
`awk -F. 'sub(FS $NF,x)' test`

or use something more readable like `rev test|cut -d. -f 2-|rev` that is more easy to read.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I think the first one may apply better,since some domain address also include the country code. I am thinking that first use rev/cut and then search for the remaining domain name. Hope this can work

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
rev domains.txt | cut -d '.' -f 2- | rev
```

But if you have more complex terminations to remove, you can use sed with an explicit list:

```
sed -r 's/\.(com(\.hk)?|org|edu|net|gov|mil)//' domains.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the advices. However, I am thinking, some domain address have two TLD, like google.com.hk. How should I cut both of them? Especially when google.com and google.com.hk both exist

Comment: @TJLiu: you can use sed, see my example.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the [^] is only for excluding single characters, not expressions so you essentially have a regexp that is:

```
match($1, /[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+[^()|.cedgilmoruv)]/, where)
```

which is why it can *not* match `ime.com` from `buisiness.time.com` since all those characters are in the [^] expression.

I couldn't find a good negative match for gawk, but did construct what's below and I hope will work for you:

```
match($1, /([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+)(\.com|\.org|\.edu|\.gov|\.mil)/, where)
print where[0]
print where[1]
print where[2]
> }' test
```

So the first part ends up in where[1] and the where[2] has the high level domain

```
business.time.com
business.time
.com
mybest.try.com
mybest.try
.com
this.is.a.example.org
this.is.a.example
.org
this.is.another.example.edu
this.is.another.example
.edu
```

Comment: This one really helps! That is exactly what I am confused of. Also, when I search the function match online, it only has two arguments. How does the third one work?

Comment: @TJ Liu This works by using the expression groups (the parenthesis around the regexp expressions) ie. ([a-z...]+) and (.com|...).  In other words, the [0] is what was matched and will be the whole string.  [1] is what was matched by the 1st group and the [2] is what was matched by the 2nd group.